# How to compare long lines with vimdif?

Tags: vim, vimdiff

I compare two version of Latex file, using vimdiff.

Lines in my file may contain as much as 30 sentences. The difference between the sentences are mostly small, like a typo, a word added or removed, word order reversed.

If a line differs between the two files, vimdiff marks the first word that differs plus the whole rest of the line in red in both files; this is too much, and additionally, makes it hard to spot differences, if present, in the marked text.

What can I do to spot these differences easier?

Is there a way to let vim diff compare files sentence by sentence instead of line by line?

Or is it possible to let vim diff mark only the words that differ within a line?

Answer (score 3):

There's a new plugin, [diffchar.vim - Highlight the difference, character by character](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4932), which apparently provides this (haven't tried it yet). In general, diffing is line-based, so any content that does not have great granularity on a line level is problematic.

A workaround would be to temporarily modify both buffers (without persisting) to introduce more line breaks, and then `:diffupdate`. Based on your [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625809/for-selected-lines-put-each-scentence-on-a-new-line-with-vim), you seem to be thinking along the same lines.